# Clicking a button to go to the next page with Python

Tags: python, selenium, post

I'm trying to click on a button on a webpage without using Selenium's .click function, so that I can scrape the contents of the next page. The button can be seen below.

[image]

I've seen other questions where a .post is used for that, but I can't seem to figure it out exactly.

Comment: But you know what is the url when you click on that button?

Comment: Can you share the url ?

Comment: Please don't use images and use actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use the .click function? For example:
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name").click()

Comment: Thats what I have right now, and its working fine. I just want to speed it up by immediately going to the post.